# Warning: SuexecUserGroup directive requires SUEXEC wrapper error

Tags: apache

We had an issue whereby permissions were replaced on the server which were then reverted.

But now I am getting continous logs of the following message in the apache error log

Warning: SuexecUserGroup directive requires SUEXEC wrapper.

Have checked the permissions and the user is set to root with the group to www-data.

Bit of a loss as I am new to the world of apache.

Any help would be great

Answer (score 1):

Put the following in the httpd.conf file:

```
<IfModule mod_suexec.c>
   Suexec On
</IfModule>
```

Then check the location and owner/mode of the suexec binary.

It as to be:

```
chgrp <whatever-group-apache-runs-with> suexec
chmod 4750 suexec
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the permission of the /usr/sbin/suexec in your OS

**chown root:root  /usr/sbin/suexec 

chmod 4755 /usr/sbin/suexec**

To explain it further i have some references to guide you more about what is all about

http://kb.odin.com/en/5225 
http://www.coderanch.com/t/110770/Linux-UNIX/permissions-meaning